# Efficiently get lattice points on line in square

Tags: python, math, geometry

A lattice point is a point with integer coordinates.

The line is the perpendicular bisect between two lattice points A and B.  (Every point on that line is equidistant from points A and B.)

How can I efficiently compute the lattice points on that perpendicular bisect line within the square 0,0 → N,N?

Here is a square, with some example points A and B ↓

[image]

The point M is the midpoint between A and B.

My thinking has taken me thus far:

The points LA, LB and RA, RB are a square you can easily compute to the left and right sides of the line AB.

The midpoint LM between A and LB, and the midpoint RM A and RB is also on the perpendicular bisect line.

So how can you use this information to very quickly compute the lattice points on the perpendicular bisect line between two points?

<sub>this isn't homework, its just hobby coding</sub>

Comment: I suggest to add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question if you want to get a proper answer!

Comment: I'm guessing from your code that (x1, y1, x2, y2) are all integers, and that the line passes though the points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2). Is that correct? And roughly how big are typical W & H?

Comment: @PM2Ring the line doesn't pass through x1, y1, x2, y2 as its perpendicular to them.  The lattice points are all equidistant from x1,y2 and x2,y2.  W and H are fairly big, over 500 and less than 1000.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark "...isn't going to cause your CPU to take off it's tracksuit pants, let alone break into a sweat". wrong way round :)

Comment: Oh, ok. I didn't closely analyze your code, so I didn't notice that. Can you easily determine a point and the slope _of the desired line_? And are the co-ords of that point integers, and can the slope be given as the ratio of a pair of integers? If so, I _may_ have a solution that's more efficient than brute force testing of 500 to 1000 x or y values.

Comment: @PM2Ring yes ignore the perpendicular bisector bit; that's just that the point on the line is the midpoint between these two and that the slope is -1/slope of the other two.  The main thing is to find the lattice points on a line given a (non-lattice) point and a slope.  The slope may not be rational.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark first it doesn't change much (its an extra division to compute a slope), and second I'm wanting to visit the lattice points gazillions of times.

Comment: Can you supply the co-ords of that non-lattice point as rational numbers, i.e. pairs of integers? If the co-ords are floats it can still be done, but it does make things a bit messier.

Comment: I regret adding my code as Karsa wanted, as this perpendicular bisector thing is a red herring.  I have a point, the coordinates of which are float.  I have a slope, which is probably not rational.  I want to visit the lattice points on that line as it passes through a box :)  The only complication from the bisector bit is rounding of the midpoint and the inaccuracy of floats.

Comment: The coords & the slope all being floats does make things messy. Floats can be approximated as rationals using continued fractions. But if the denominators of the rationals are large then the line may not pass _exactly_ through many lattice points in the desired range, if any.

Comment: If the slope is not rational, doesn't that mean there are no lattice points at all? f(x) = mx + b will always produce irrational numbers when m is irrational, and x and b are rational. (unless x = 0)

Comment: Once you introduce floating point arithmetic into a problem that is hard to undo and get integer certainty anymore. I think the best you're gonna do is get a solution within some tolerance. What is wrong with testing each X in your domain and checking the tolerance of |Y-int(Y)|. Requiring Y==int(Y) seems unrealistic since you've computed Y using floating point arithmetic as it is.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: That's what I suspected when I first saw the question, but it wasn't exactly clear then, due to the OP saying that the known point & slope of the desired line couldn't be expressed as simple ratios. Fortunately, he's cleaned up the question considerably.

Answer (score 5):

I *might* be over-thinking this, going by matovitch's latest code draft (which I've only had a brief glance at), but anyway...

Let A = (A.x, A.y), B = (B.x, B.y), where (A.x, A.y, B.x, B.y) are integers.
Then line *p*, the perpendicular bisector of AB, passes through
M = (M.x, M.y) = ((A.x + B.x)/2, (A.y + B.y)/2)

The product of the slopes of AB and *p* is -1, thus the slope of *p* is
-(B.x - A.x) / (B.y - A.y)
and hence in point-slope form the equation of *p* is
(y - M.y) / (x - M.x) = (A.x - B.x) / (B.y - A.y)

Rearranging,
y*(B.y - A.y) + x*(B.x - A.x) = M.y * (B.y - A.y) + M.x * (B.x - A.x)
= ((B.y + A.y) * (B.y - A.y) + (B.x + A.x) * (B.x - A.x)) / 2
= (B.y^2 - A.y^2 + B.x^2 - A.x^2) / 2

Clearly, for any lattice point (x, y), y*(B.y - A.y) + x*(B.x - A.x) must be an integer. So the line *p* will only pass through lattice points if (B.y^2 - A.y^2 + B.x^2 - A.x^2) is even.

Now (B.y^2 - A.y^2 + B.x^2 - A.x^2) is even if & only if (A.x + B.x + A.y + B.y) is even, which is true if an even number of (A.x, A.y, B.x, B.y) are odd. In what follows, I assume that (A.x + B.x + A.y + B.y) is even.

Let
dx = (B.x - A.x)
dy = (B.y - A.y)
s = (B.y^2 - A.y^2 + B.x^2 - A.x^2) / 2
So the equation of *p* is
y * dy + x * dx = s

Because y, dy, x, dx & s are all integers that equation is a linear Diophantine equation, and the standard way to find the solutions of such an equation is to use the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm). Our equation will only have solutions if the gcd (greatest common divisor) of dx & dy divides s. Fortunately, that's true in this case, but I won't give the proof here.

Let Y, X be a solution of y * dy + x * dx = g, where g is the gcd(dx, dy), i.e.,
Y * dy + X * dx = g
Y * dy/g + X * dx/g = 1

Let dy' = dy/g, dx' = dx/g, s' = s/g, so
Y * dy' + X * dx' = 1

Dividing the last equation for *p* through by g, we get
y * dy' + x * dx' = s'

And we can now construct one solution for it.
(Y * s') * dy' + (X * s') * dx' = s'
i.e., (X * s', Y * s') is a lattice point on the line.

We can get all solutions like this:
(Y * s' + k * dx') * dy' + (X * s' - k * dy') * dx' = s', for all integers k.

To restrict the solutions to the grid from (0, 0) to (W, H), we need to solve these inequalities for k:
0 <= X * s' - k * dy' <= W and 0 <= Y * s' + k * dx' <= H

I won't show the solutions of those inequalities right here; for the details see the code below.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

''' Lattice Line

    Find lattice points, i.e, points with integer co-ordinates,
    on the line that is the perpendicular bisector of the line segment AB,
    where A & B are lattice points.

    See http://stackoverflow.com/q/31265139/4014959

    Written by PM 2Ring 2015.07.08
    Code for Euclid's algorithm & the Diophantine solver written 2010.11.27
'''

from __future__ import division
import sys
from math import floor, ceil

class Point(object):
    ''' A simple 2D point '''
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x, self.y = x, y

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Point(%s, %s)" % (self.x, self.y)

    def __str__(self):
        return "(%s, %s)" % (self.x, self.y)


def euclid(a, b):
    ''' Euclid's extended algorithm for the GCD.
    Returns a list of tuples of (dividend, quotient, divisor, remainder) 
    '''
    if a < b: 
        a, b = b, a

    k = []
    while True:
        q, r = a // b, a % b
        k.append((a, q, b, r))
        if r == 0:
            break
        a, b = b, r
    return k


def dio(aa, bb):
    ''' Linear Diophantine solver 
    Returns [x, aa, y, bb, d]: x*aa + y*bb = d
    '''
    a, b = abs(aa), abs(bb)
    swap = a < b
    if swap:
        a, b = b, a

    #Handle trivial cases
    if a == b:
        eqn = [2, a, -1, a]
    elif a % b == 0:
        q = a // b
        eqn = [1, a, 1-q, b]
    else:
        #Generate quotients & remainders list
        z = euclid(a, b)[::-1]

        #Build equation from quotients & remainders
        eqn = [0, 0, 1, 0]
        for v in z[1:]:
            eqn = [eqn[2], v[0], eqn[0] - eqn[2]*v[1], v[2]]

    #Rearrange & fix signs, if required
    if swap:
        eqn = eqn[2:] + eqn[:2]

    if aa < 0:
        eqn[:2] = [-eqn[0], -eqn[1]]
    if bb < 0:
        eqn[2:] = [-eqn[2], -eqn[3]]

    d = eqn[0]*eqn[1] + eqn[2]*eqn[3]
    if d < 0:
        eqn[0], eqn[2], d = -eqn[0], -eqn[2], -d

    return eqn + [d]


def lattice_line(pA, pB, pC):
    ''' Find lattice points, i.e, points with integer co-ordinates, on
    the line that is the perpendicular bisector of the line segment AB,
    Only look for points in the rectangle from (0,0) to C

    Let M be the midpoint of AB. Then M = ((A.x + B.x)/2, (A.y + B.y)/2),
    and the equation of the perpendicular bisector of AB is
    (y - M.y) / (x - M.x) = (A.x - B.x) / (B.y - A.y)
    '''

    nosolutions = 'No solutions found'

    dx = pB.x - pA.x
    dy = pB.y - pA.y

    #Test parity of co-ords to see if there are solutions
    if (dx + dy) % 2 == 1:
        print nosolutions
        return

    #Handle horizontal & vertical lines
    if dx == 0:
        #AB is vertical, so bisector is horizontal
        y = pB.y + pA.y
        if dy == 0 or y % 2 == 1:
            print nosolutions
            return
        y //= 2
        for x in xrange(pC.x + 1):
            print Point(x, y)
        return

    if dy == 0:
        #AB is horizontal, so bisector is vertical
        x = pB.x + pA.x
        if x % 2 == 1:
            print nosolutions
            return
        x //= 2
        for y in xrange(pC.y + 1):
            print Point(x, y)
        return

    #Compute s = ((pB.x + pA.x)*dx + (pB.y + pA.y)*dy) / 2
    #s will always be an integer since (dx + dy) is even
    #The desired line is y*dy + x*dx = s
    s = (pB.x**2 - pA.x**2 + pB.y**2 - pA.y**2) // 2

    #Find ex, ey, g: ex * dx + ey * dy = g, where g is the gcd of (dx, dy)
    #Note that g also divides s
    eqn = dio(dx, dy)
    ex, ey, g = eqn[::2]

    #Divide the parameters of the equation by the gcd
    dx //= g
    dy //= g
    s //= g

    #Find lattice limits
    xlo = (ex * s - pC.x) / dy
    xhi = ex * s / dy
    if dy < 0:
        xlo, xhi = xhi, xlo

    ylo = -ey * s / dx
    yhi = (pC.y - ey * s) / dx
    if dx < 0:
        ylo, yhi = yhi, ylo

    klo = int(ceil(max(xlo, ylo)))
    khi = int(floor(min(xhi, yhi)))
    print 'Points'
    for k in xrange(klo, khi + 1):
        x = ex * s - dy * k
        y = ey * s + dx * k
        assert x*dx + y*dy == s
        print Point(x, y)


def main():
    if len(sys.argv) != 7:
        print '''    Find lattice points, i.e, points with integer co-ordinates,
    on the line that is the perpendicular bisector of the line segment AB,
    where A & B are lattice points with co-ords (xA, yA) & (xB, yB).
    Only print lattice points in the rectangle from (0, 0) to (W, H)

Usage:
    %s xA yA xB yB W H''' % sys.argv[0]
        exit(1)

    coords = [int(s) for s in sys.argv[1:]]
    pA = Point(*coords[0:2])
    pB = Point(*coords[2:4])
    pC = Point(*coords[4:6])
    lattice_line(pA, pB, pC)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I haven't tested this code extensively, but it *appears* to work correctly. :)

Comment: This *does* seem to work correctly :)  It can return points outside pC though.

Comment: The way my thinking is taking me is that there is a builtin `gcd` function in the `fractions` package.  The lattice points on our line are mirrored across the line AB, so its either a lattice point or half way between two...

Comment: I have checked this code empirically using my sim and I have a verification step that would catch if ever the code emits a dud.  However, its still quite slow.  Could we adapt it to use `fractions.gcd` for example?  Must sleep now :)  thx

Comment: @Will The `fractions.gcd` function isn't much use in solving the general case. It only returns the gcd, but we also need ex & ey in order to find a lattice point on the line. OTOH, if the midpoint of AB _is_ a lattice point, so we already have a lattice point on the line, then we _don't_ need ex & ey, and so we can simplify things considerably, and then a simple gcd function is all we need. You could use [fractions.gcd](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/fractions.py) for that, but that code can return a negative number as the gcd, which is a bit annoying.

Comment: @Will: If you give me some example input data that returns points outside pC I'll try to figure out what's wrong with the logic of my lattice limits code. Of course, you can eliminate such points with a simple `if` test, but it would be nice if the code didn't generate such points in the first place.

Comment: Regards the midpoint, it is either a lattice point or it is exactly midway between two?  Regards bounds, here are a couple of examples: `pt=(1101,-211), A=(2,1), B=(349,618), C=(619,619)` and `pt=(419,686), A=(487,616), B=(349,618), C=(619,619)`

Comment: @Will I corrected my code, it seems to be working (given some example you gave)...See here to compile and run (click edit) : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa22a3c9ab68d185

Comment: @Will Again...I don't limit the search to a square but it shouldn't be too hard to add this constraint.

Comment: @Will: That's weird. When I run the code I don't get out of bounds points for either of those sets of A & B.

Comment: @matovitch: Please put any comments that relate specifically to your answer under your answer. Putting them here's a bit confusing.

Comment: @PM 2Ring Sorry that's indeed a better idea...You may double-check the result with coliru if you want too.

Comment: @Will: You said: "Regards the midpoint, it is either a lattice point or it is exactly midway between two?" That's correct. If the midpoint isn't a lattice point, it can be midway between two lattice points, either orthogonally or diagonally. But in either of those cases, knowing the midpoint doesn't help us much in finding a point on the line that _is_ a lattice point.

Comment: @Will: What version of Python are you using? My lattice limits code can give incorrect results on Python 2 if you don't have the `from __future__ import division` line at the start of the script.

Comment: Ah I will try with the import division!  Is the span between lattice points a function of the gcd?

Comment: @matovitch PM2Ring here's my progress so far incorporating symmetry into my heuristics ... http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/52496/uniquely-separated-pixels/52541?noredirect=1#comment126280_52496 :)  Thx for all the help :thumbup:

Answer (score 2):

Ok I sure did not explained my solution clearly, let's start again. Given a grid with twice the resolution, the middle point M will be on the grid. The minimal direction vector of the perpendicular bissector is given by V = (yB - yA, xA - xB) / gcd(yB - yA, xA - xB). Then we look at M and V modulo the lattice Z/2Z x Z/2Z to check if one can find a point M + iV with even coordinates (aka on the coarse grid). We can then compute a starting point S = M + jV (j = 0 or 1 in fact) on the lattice and get the famous set of points as {S + iV, i integer}.

[Now running ;)]
This C++ code print S and V, aka the nearest lattice point to the middle and the vector one can add or subtract to get the next/previous lattice point. You then have to filter the points to get those inside the square (test it here : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ba9f8aec45e1c2ea) :

```
int gcd(int n1, int n2)
{
    n1 = (n1 > 0) ? n1 : -n1;
    n2 = (n2 > 0) ? n2 : -n2;

    if (n1 > n2) 
    {
        int t = n1;
        n1 = n2;
        n2 = t; 
    } 

    while (n2 % n1 != 0)
    {
        int tmp = n2 % n1;
        n2 = n1;
        n1 = tmp; 
    }

    return n1;
}

struct Point
{

    const Point& operator=(const Point& rhs)
    {
        x = rhs.x;
        y = rhs.y;

        return *this;
    }

    const Point& operator+=(const Point& rhs)
    {
        x += rhs.x;
        y += rhs.y;

        return *this;
    }

    const Point& operator-=(const Point& rhs)
    {
        x += rhs.x;
        y += rhs.y;

        return *this;
    }

    const Point& operator/=(int rhs)
    {
        x /= rhs;
        y /= rhs;

        return *this;
    }

    const Point& reduce()
    {
        return *this /= gcd(x, y);
    }

    int x;
    int y;
};

const Point operator+(Point lhs, const Point& rhs)
{
    lhs += rhs;
    return lhs;
}

const Point operator-(Point lhs, const Point& rhs)
{
    lhs -= rhs;
    return lhs;
}

const Point operator/(Point lhs, int rhs)
{
    lhs /= rhs;
    return lhs;
}

bool findBase(Point& p1, Point& p2, Point& oBase, Point& oDir)
{
    Point m = p1 + p2;
    Point v = {p2.y - p1.y, p1.x - p2.x};

    oDir = v.reduce();

    if (m.x % 2 == 0 && m.y % 2 == 0)
    {
        oBase = m / 2;
        return true;
    } 
    else if (((m.x % 2 == 0 && v.x % 2 == 0) &&
              (m.y % 2 == 1 && v.y % 2 == 1)) ||
             ((m.x % 2 == 1 && v.x % 2 == 1) &&
              (m.y % 2 == 0 && v.y % 2 == 0)) ||
             ((m.x % 2 == 1 && v.x % 2 == 1) &&
              (m.y % 2 == 1 && v.y % 2 == 1)))
    {
        oBase = (m + v) / 2;
        return true;
    }
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: [This comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31265139/efficiently-get-lattice-points-on-line-in-square#comment50527958_31265139) says the line ***does not*** pass through (x1, y1) & (x2, y2)

Comment: This is not a true issue, if the slope is real (which it is not for ieee754 encoding) you don't cross any points (math), if it's rational you can easily find a fraction to simplify (http://www.mathsisfun.com/converting-decimals-fractions.html <- but in binary for ieee754 floats)

Comment: Ah it is perpendicular ? Then (y2 - y1, x1 - x2) direct this line and you can apply the same reasonning.

Comment: @matovitch correct, only the slope is probably not rational.  I just used -1 / slope to get the perpendicular; i that right too?

Comment: There's a better way to convert floats to rationals: use [continued fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Best_rational_approximations).

Comment: @Will, if you start from a lattice point and the slope is not rational, then the starting point is the only lattice point you'll cross (otherwise you can express a rational slope).

Comment: @PM2Ring Continued fraction are used to approach algebraic numbers classically not for finding an exact solution I think.

Comment: @Will The slope is rational each time in fact, you can replace the -1/(rat_slope) by (y2 - y1) / (x1 - x2)...or something like that.

Comment: @matovitch Well, technically, all ieee754 floats are rationals with a binary power denominator, but that denominator may be _huge_. Continued fractions _can_ be used to approximate rationals by rationals with lower denominators; see the Wikipedia link for an example.

Comment: @PM2Ring, matovitch of course, if the line is perpendicular between two *lattice* points A and B then does that mean the line will always have a rational slope?  And will two lattice points on that line be derivable from the coordinates of A and B?  Must get some graph paper...

Comment: @Will. Do you mean the desired line is the perpendicular bisector of the line AB, where A & B are both lattice points? If so, it's slope is certainly rational. And we also have a point with rational co-ords on the desired line: the midpoint of AB.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes, I said in my first comment ieee754 floats are rationals...Thanks for the link about continued fraction I will look into it. But if you want an exact "mathematical" answer this is not helpful. :(

Comment: @PM2Ring matovitch I have completely revamped the question, with new diagrams.   It looks reasonable, for example, to say that if the points M and LM are not lattice points then there are *no* lattice points?

Comment: @Will: M doesn't have to be a lattice point. Here's a simple example. Let A=(0,1) & B=(1,0). Then M=(1/2, 1/2) and the line passes through (n,n) for all n. But there is a simple test to determine if the line passes through no lattice points (on the infinite plane). Let A=(xA,yA), B=(xB,yB). Then the line will pass through lattice points if & only if xA+yA+xB+yB is even, i.e., if an even number of (xA,yA,xB,yB) are odd. I'll write up an answer with some explanation & some code, but I may not post it today.

Comment: @Will My answer is clearly an ugly draft, but if you read between the line (and I know PM2Ring does), you have everything to write an efficient solution. I spoke about the middle point problem in my two last edits.